# How can i create custom image view so that the pic which i have taken should be fit into that image view

Tags: android

I am trying to make an application, which fetches the image from the storage and place it into that application image size so that it looks good for it.

Comment: Although i edit your question,but its not clear what you actully wana do...and what you mean by "application image size"

Comment: add android:sacleType="centerCrop" property in your imageview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaling bitmaps from memory can be very memory intensive. To avoid crashing your app on old devices, I recommend doing this.

I use these two methods to load a bitmap and scale it down. I split them into two functions. `createLightweightScaledBitmapFromStream()` uses `options.inSampleSize` to perform a rough scaling to the required dimensions. Then, `createScaledBitmapFromStream()` uses a more memory intensive `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()` to finish scaling the image to the desired resolution.

Call `createScaledBitmapFromStream()` and you should be all set.

Lightweight scaling

```
public static Bitmap createLightweightScaledBitmapFromStream(InputStream is, int minShrunkWidth, int minShrunkHeight, Bitmap.Config config) {

  BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is, 32 * 1024);
  try {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    if (config != null) {
      options.inPreferredConfig = config;
    }

    final BitmapFactory.Options decodeBoundsOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    decodeBoundsOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    bis.mark(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis, null, decodeBoundsOptions);
    bis.reset();

    final int width = decodeBoundsOptions.outWidth;
    final int height = decodeBoundsOptions.outHeight;
    Log.v("Original bitmap dimensions: %d x %d", width, height);
    int sampleRatio = Math.max(width / minShrunkWidth, height / minShrunkHeight);
    if (sampleRatio >= 2) {
      options.inSampleSize = sampleRatio;
    }
    Log.v("Bitmap sample size = %d", options.inSampleSize);

    Bitmap ret = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis, null, options);
    Log.d("Sampled bitmap size = %d X %d", options.outWidth, options.outHeight);
    return ret;
  } catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("Error resizing bitmap from InputStream.", e);
  } finally {
    Util.ensureClosed(bis);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Final Scaling (Calls lightweight scaling first)

```
public static Bitmap createScaledBitmapFromStream(InputStream is, int maxWidth, int maxHeight, Bitmap.Config config) {

  // Start by grabbing the bitmap from file, sampling down a little first if the image is huge.
  Bitmap tempBitmap = createLightweightScaledBitmapFromStream(is, maxWidth, maxHeight, config);

  Bitmap outBitmap = tempBitmap;
  int width = tempBitmap.getWidth();
  int height = tempBitmap.getHeight();

  // Find the greatest ration difference, as this is what we will shrink both sides to.
  float ratio = calculateBitmapScaleFactor(width, height, maxWidth, maxHeight);
  if (ratio < 1.0f) { // Don't blow up small images, only shrink bigger ones.
    int newWidth = (int) (ratio * width);
    int newHeight = (int) (ratio * height);
    Log.v("Scaling image further down to %d x %d", newWidth, newHeight);
    outBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
    Log.d("Final bitmap dimensions: %d x %d", outBitmap.getWidth(), outBitmap.getHeight());
    tempBitmap.recycle();
  }
  return outBitmap;
}
```